# Swift core data removing entries in one to many relationships

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm using Xcode 6.4 and Swift in iOS 8.4 project
I have a model with one to many relationship

```
class Account: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var userId: Int
    @NSManaged var accessToken: String?
    @NSManaged var userName: String
    @NSManaged var sex: String
    @NSManaged var email: String
    @NSManaged var avatarUrl: String?

    @NSManaged var friends: NSSet
}

class User: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var id: Int
    @NSManaged var userName: String
    @NSManaged var sex: String
    @NSManaged var email: String
    @NSManaged var avatarUrl: String

}
```

When I'm trying to remove all friends it doesn't work:

```
extension Account {

    func replaceFriends(friends:[User]) {
        var friendsList = self.mutableSetValueForKey("friends")
        friendsList.removeAllObjects()
        friendsList.addObjectsFromArray(friends)
    }

    func getFriends() -> [User] {
        return self.mutableSetValueForKey("friends").allObjects as! [User]
    }

}

class AccountDao: BaseDao {

    private class func findAccount() -> Account? {
        if let result = moc.executeFetchRequest(NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Account"), error: nil) as? [Account] {
            if (!result.isEmpty) {
                return result[0]
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    class func getAccount() -> Account {
        return findAccount() ??
                NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Account", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! Account;
    }
}
```

During saving I'm setting empty array:

```
class func saveObjectContext() -> Bool {
        var error: NSError?

        var account = AccountDao.getAccount()
        account.replaceFriends([User]())
        if !moc.save(&error) {
            self.log.error("Error during saving context, \(error)")
            return false
        } else {
            println("Count in log \(AccountDao.getAccount().getFriends().count)")
            self.log.info("Info save context \(error)")
            return true
        }
    }
```

In log it returns 0:
`Count in log 0`

But in ControllerView still I'm getting `AccountDao.getAccount().getFriends().count == 1`. Method `replaceFriends` works only first time when I fetch and save data. And it save changes for simple properties like `userName` but not for `friends`. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that in relation one to many **Account** -> **User** without inverse relationship in **User**, after changing list in **Account** every user in list have to be marked that has changed (property `updated == true`). But it always was set to `false`.

I added additional property to User, and after every change of list I had to change this property like `user.toUpdate = true`. After this change everything is working fine.